# How can I choose the vue.config.js location?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I am wanting to move my `vue.config.js` file to somewhere else than my root directory. Per the [configuration reference](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)...

> `vue.config.js` is an optional config file that will be automatically
>   loaded by `@vue/cli-service` if it's present in your project root (next
>   to `package.json`)

However, I'd like to move it per my use case. Is this possible via [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack) or [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack)? Another technique? I am using `@vue/cli` version **3.x**

Comment: @Matt Wow thanks for the link. This is exactly what I need. My google-fu did not surface this so thank you for the reference. I may close this out but will leave it up to community opinion to dupe it for higher visibility since I didn't see that Q at all...

Comment: no worries, I didn't know about this env variable until just now. I found it in the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/f9a9880d93eefb9ac0d089c8566c04c9b1b08fa3/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js#L295) and then Google'd from there